# I am facing problem to get value from string this is not a json also so how to fetch value from given string

Tags: json

a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:8:"priority";i:0;s:6:"amount";s:2:"20";s:4:"type";s:5:"above";s:5:"total";s:1:"0";}}

how to get s:2 from this string it is not a json also then how to get this value

Answer (score 0):

This isn't json, but have a structure.

May be - first letter - it's type, second length, for example:

`a:1:{...` - element `a` - array? have 1 element {}

`i:0;` - element `i` - integer? have 0 element

`a:4:{` - element `a` have 4 element?  in  {} - it's wrong

`s:8:"priority"` - `s` string?, have length 8 for "priority"

etc.

You my parse this string to json

```
res=[0,
["priority",0,"amount","20","type","above","total","0"]]
```

And get value s:2:"20" - from array, for example in JS `res[1][4]`

Comment: but how to parse this string as json